# Bayes' theorem to know how many of my dates (fruit) are bad!

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I bought a container of dates (fruit) (containing $57$ dates in total). I started opening them to see if they're good or bad (do have warms inside or not), and after opening $7$ of them I found that the first $5$ were bad whereas the $2$ last were good.

I usually buy these dates' containers and I would estimate that one third of it are bad dates$^{(*)}$.

How can I estimate (or rather improve my estimation, I guess using Bayes' theorem) the number of bad dates I have in the container considering the evidence I have (i.e. $5$ first opened dates are good and last $2$ bad).

$^{(*)}$: I still buy them though because they're cheap ;-)

**Spoiler alert**: I can check the real numbers after I open all dates :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how strongly you believe in your prior knowledge. Say $k$ represents the strength of your belief. The higher $k$ is, the more you believe in your prior. Using beta distribution as the conjugate prior, $B(\alpha=k/3, \beta=2k/3)$ and modeling with binomial, the posterior distribution is proportional to $p^{5+\alpha-1}(1-p)^{2+\beta-1}$.

Your new estimate for proportion of bad dates becomes $\frac{5+\alpha}{7+\alpha+\beta}=\frac{5+k/3}{7+k}$. In other words, it's like you're adding imaginary dates ($k/3$ good ones and $2k/3$ bad ones) to your samples and use the frequentist method.

Comment: what's the range of variation of $k$?

Comment: Any positive number

Comment: Is there a reason for using the beta distribution? the binomial I guess is because we have two choices (either bad or good)!

Comment: You're right about binomial for modeling the number of "successes" (bad dates). There's no real reason other than ease of computation. Beta distribution is a conjugate prior for binomial, meaning the posterior distribution will also be a beta distribution. In your case, the posterior is $B(5+\alpha-1, 2+\beta-1)$.

Comment: The answer seems logical, even though I can't seem to attach a meaning to the beta parameters, like why would you choose $\alpha = k/3$?

Comment: Because you mentioned you believed 1/3 were bad. $k$ is like the number of dates you've bought to this day, so you've seen $k/3$ bad ones and $2k/3$ good ones.

Comment: Okay, I guessed that. What I mean is for example why not $\alpha = 2k/3$ and $\beta = k/3$. If you would, what's the role of the "shape" parameters of the beta distribution that makes this choice the one to choose? (this might have gotten out of the scope of the question, sorry for that, my understanding of distributions is limited!)

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. The parameters are chosen so that the mean of the beta distribution $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta) = 1/3$. If we'd chosen $\alpha=2k/3$ and $\beta=k/3$, we'd be modelling proportion of good ones instead of bad ones.

Comment: It's clear now, thanks :-) By the way, after counting them, I found 20 bad dates and 37 good ones out of 57. The proportions are 35.09% bad vs 64.91% good. So, I guess my estimation wasn't so bad after all :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really my territory, but I actually don't think you'd need to / can apply Bayes' Theorem here. Rather, it's more of a statistics problem, like a 1-sample proportion t-test, where the observed value is $5/7$, or $71.4\%$, the degrees of freedom is $(n-1) = 6$, and the null hypothesis of $33\%$. Working this out, we get a p-value of around $0.015$, which means that around $1.5\%$ of the time, you'd expect to get at more than or equal to $5/7$ bad dates! Doesn't totally answer your question of the expected value, but know that if you're testing to see if you had a normal container, statistically speaking you probably don't!

Comment: why can't I apply Bayes' theorem?